# Masters/Doctoral Thesis on latextemplates: Change FIGURE (small caps) caption to figure

Tags: captions

> Template can be found here:
>   https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

```
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{figure}[h!]

     \centering

    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Figures/Executiontime}

        \caption[Execution time]{Execution time}
        \label{fig:Execution time}

    \end{figure}
```

it gives me an output like this [image]

How i can change from FIGURE 4.5  to Figure 4.5 in small letters rather than caps

Comment: I think it depends on the documentclass and the packages you use... So please give a minimum working example starting from the documentclass command and ending in \end{document}... Welcome!

Comment: Well this is actually for my thesis and i am using this template from latextemplates.com       https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Look for the file `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`.
- Open it in a text editor of your choice. I recommend `notepad++`.
- Lines `202-203` are important.
- Delete `labelfont=sc` (`sc` = Small Caps, google it!) or replace it with `labelfont=bf` for example.
- Have a look at the [`caption` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) for further information.
- **Recommended:** As you can read in the comments, alternatively, you can just use `\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}` before `\begin{document}`.

---

```
\RequirePackage{caption} % Required for customising the captions
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast,font=small,labelfont=sc,margin=50pt}
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]
(using option `labelfont=bf`)

Comment: Eh... usually editing `.cls` files is not recommended, unless it is a really bad class (which will be improved by editing, most likely ;-))

Comment: `\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}` before `\begin{document}`  in the document is enough, without editing the `.cls` file

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. Since the `cls` file is not part of a distribution like MiKTeX I did not think that is a "big deal".

Comment: It's one of those template classes with issues. Ask @Johannes_B for more information ;-)

Comment: Making a change in the preamble should  be the only answer shown. Changing the class file is just wrong, imho. See the class file itself. Also, it makes support so so so very much harder.

Comment: @Johannes_B I edited the answer slightly to reflect your comment. Thanks. How do you get to read such an old question? :)

Comment: Bugged me a long time. Also, I regularly search for questions concerning MDT.